# When does Delphi honor `inline` and when not?

Tags: delphi, optimization, inline, delphi-2007

I was tying to optimize a piece of code that has this construct:

```
while (i > 0) do begin
  Dec(i);
```

This looks inefficient, so I tried to do this:

```
while (Dec(i) >= 0) do begin
```

That doesn't work because Dec is a procedure and not a function.

So I rewrite it to:

```
procedure Withloop;
var
  ....
  function Decr(var a: integer): integer; inline;
  begin
    Dec(a);
    Result:= a;
  end;

...
  while (Decr(i) >= 0) do begin
```

But this gets compiled into:

```
SDIMAIN.pas.448: while (Decr(i) >= 0) do begin
00468EE5 8BC4             mov eax,esp
00468EE7 E8D0FEFFFF       call Decr          <<--- A call??
00468EEC 85C0             test eax,eax
00468EEE 0F8D12FFFFFF     jnl $00468e06
00468EF4 EB01             jmp $00468ef7
```

However in another part of the program, it inlines a function just fine.
What rule of thumb (or hard rule) can I use to know to Delphi will honor the `inline` directive?

Comment: Did you try to turn compiler optimization off and see what happen?

Comment: Contrary to your statement - I think your first block of code is the most efficient here.

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize a *loop counter* of all things? Integer arithmetic is extremely cheap and the decrement only happens once per iteration, so if the loop does anything interesting at all, that will take the vast majority of the time. And that's not even touching on the question whether this loop is a good canidate for optimization (is it a hotspot or does it only account for 0.5% of the total runtime). And if you know a bit about how machine code looks like, you'll realize that the first two versions can easily be compiled to the same code. Optimization fail.

Comment: @delnan, I kind of hate it when people assume you're an idiot. Of course the loop is `hot` or I would not be bothering. The test does more but I reduced it to the essence. Also I know you cannot inline asm functions, so the logical choice: `function Decr(var a: integer): integer; inline;
  begin asm
    DEC EAX
  end; end;` is out.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you'll do better than the first block of code. And why would the second block of code compiler to something faster than the first block, even if it was valid? I don't think delnan is not assuming that you are an idiot. Plenty of people ask questions about optimization that are founded on gross misconceptions. Since you didn't state that this particular loop is the hot point in your code how could we tell. Now, if you do anything at all in your loop, then the while test and the dec will be insignificant so perhaps delnan has a point.

Comment: @David Because the `Dec EAX` will set the flags and then you can jump based on that, so you don't have to run the `test eax,eax`, saving one instruction.

Comment: @Johan So write some inline assembler yourself and then you'll see it makes little difference since you surely have something inside your loop. And why don't you use a for loop?

Comment: @David I cannot use a for loop because the count maybe 0 to start with.

Comment: @Johan I don't see why that means you can't use a for loop. It looks just like a for to me: one decrement per iteration.

Comment: @david, Yes it is, but the loop can be executed 0 or more times, If I'm not mistaken `for` always runs at least once.

Comment: @Johan You are mistaken. For loops can run 0 times. Always make sure your loop counter is a signed integer. In fact always use `Integer`.

Comment: Sorry, but I've seens way too many guys wasting much time with pointless optimiizations attempts to welcome "how do I optimize this code the compiler propably already optimizes as much as possible". Still, I highly doubt that *a single redundant `test` instruction* is making any difference - did you look at the disassembly of the actual code and profile it? (Sorry I'm annoying, I'm just that skeptic.) And I'd assume that the last version, inlined, would result in the same code, as inlining likely leads to the same IR (before codegen) as the first version.

Comment: @David, delnan, anyway did a test before and put the for loop in runtime went down from 3,95 million cycles to 3.76 million cycles.

Comment: @delnan, agree with your last part, I just wanted to see if I can steer the compiler without having to use assembly. Problem with assembly is that you cannot change your algorithm anymore so you blind yourself to a different way of approaching the problem. That's why I want to stay in Pascal for as long as possible. And try out different algorithms to see which works.

Comment: @David Thanks, for the `for` heads up, I must have had this notion stuck in my head for a long time.

Comment: `for` loops would be pretty useless if there were some magic restriction making them run at least once even if you do something like `for i := -1 to 0 to`...

Comment: @Andreas pardon the nitpicking, but that loop would run for -1 and 0. You probably meant `for i:=0 to -1` :)

Comment: @Magicmaster: Oh, d'oh! *Embarrassed*! ;) Of course, you'r right!

Comment: oh... I thought it was meant to be `for i := -1 downto 0 do` ;)

Comment: Turns out the speed gain is due to the for-loop allowing for better code generation. Guess Delphi can free up an extra register now that it knows `i` will not change inside the loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`Delphi Documentation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions#Using_the_inline_Directive) enumerates the conditions under which inlining does or does not occur:

> - Inlining will not occur on any form of late-bound method. This includes
>     virtual, dynamic, and message methods.
> - Routines containing assembly code will not be inlined.
> - Constructors and destructors will not be inlined.
> - The main program block, unit initialization, and unit finalization
>     blocks cannot be inlined.
> - Routines that are not defined before use cannot be inlined.
> - Routines that take open array parameters cannot be inlined.
> - Code can be inlined within packages, however, inlining never occurs across
>     package boundaries.
> - No inlining is done between units that are circularly dependent. This
>     includes indirect circular
>     dependencies, for example, unit A uses
>     unit B, and unit B uses unit C which
>     in turn uses unit A. In this example,
>     when compiling unit A, no code from
>     unit B or unit C will be inlined in
>     unit A.
> - The compiler can inline code when a unit is in a circular dependency, as
>     long as the code to be inlined comes
>     from a unit outside the circular
>     relationship. In the above example, if
>     unit A also used unit D, code from
>     unit D could be inlined in A, since it
>     is not involved in the circular
>     dependency.
> - If a routine is defined in the interface section and it accesses
>     symbols defined in the implementation
>     section, that routine cannot be
>     inlined.
> - If a routine marked with inline uses external symbols from other units, all
>     of those units must be listed in the
>     uses statement, otherwise the routine
>     cannot be inlined.
> - Procedures and functions used in conditional expressions in while-do
>     and repeat-until statements cannot be
>     expanded inline.
> - Within a unit, the body for an inline function should be defined
>     before calls to the function are made.
>     Otherwise, the body of the function,
>     which is  not known to the compiler
>     when it reaches the call site, cannot
>     be expanded inline.

In your case check this condition:

> Procedures and functions used in conditional expressions in while-do and repeat-until statements cannot be expanded inline.

Answer (score 10):

For some reason the compiler does not inline `while` loop control expressions. [Hallvard Vassbotn](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/10/more-fun-with-enumerators.html) discussed the problem some time ago (read the end of the article).

Comment: Quick summary of the last part or the article: `while True do begin if Decr(i) < 0 then Break;` inlines Decr.