# Share common definition between Delphi and C++ projects

Tags: c++, delphi

Is there an elegant way to share a common symbol definition between a Delphi and C++ (Visual Studio) project?

The symbol might be defined or not defined depending on the circumstances. It is obviously possible to just define the symbol in both projects, but you might comment it out in one project and forget about it in the other (or vice versa).

If this is possible, I'm guessing the symbol would need be put into a .h or .inc file and included in both projects.

```
// Delphi
{$DEFINE COMMON_SYMBOL}
//...
SOME_CONSTANT = {$IFDEF COMMON_SYMBOL} 80 {$ELSE} 40 {$ENDIF};

// C++
#define COMMON_SYMBOL
//...
#ifdef COMMON_SYMBOL
    #define SOME_CONSTANT 80
#else
    #define SOME_CONSTANT 40
#endif
```

In the above code, if `COMMON_SYMBOL` is defined, then `SOME_CONSTANT` is 80, otherwise it is 40.

Comment: Maybe it would be enough to define the SOME_CONSTANT with shared specific values in both projects at once? That would be easy... But conditional defining pre-processor symbols via pre-processor itself is not

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work because the two compilers and IDEs are totally different (Embarcadero and Microsoft).

Comment: Uhm... it's not the different vendors, that makes this hard. It's the fact, that you are dealing with two different **programming languages**. You'd have the same trouble when sharing code between C++ and F#, even when using compilers produced by the same vendor.

Comment: "how that would work" - what? defining constants is easy, it is almost the same in C and Pascal for numerical constants: `NAME=VALUE;NAME=VALUE;.....`  Then in modern Delphi you can check those constants with $IF - but hardly in MS VC++

Comment: @Arioch'The: In C++ that would be an **assignment**. Defining a (preprocessor) symbol is a different story.

Comment: There are a number of custom pre-processors in Delphi, some of them can even be integrated into IDE like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141319/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/dpp32 which maybe can be extended to have such functionality. But if there are such tools for Visual Studio is beyond me. Anyway, that would be deviation from the language itself.

Comment: @IInspectable: Hmm, of course you're right. Just tried compiling `{IFDEF BLAH}` in Visual Studio and `#ifdef BLAH` in Delphi and unsurprisingly both are respectively not valid C++ and Delphi ! Thinking the answer must be no...

Comment: @IInspectable technically you are correct: constants are not citizens of pre-processor realm (and I meant constants not variables). There was no constant in C (w/o pluses) back then. However I see little practical difference in the examples of topicstarter. Except that he should better typed `#define SOME_CONSTANT (80)` instead

Comment: @AlainD maybe you have an x-y-z trouble. Let as change the angle. What the end result do you try to achieve using (or misusing) such a conditional compiling ? Maybe that end result can be reached with other means ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: I have a constant which defines the size of a member of a structure. A pointer to the structure is passed from the GUI (written in Delphi) to a C++ DLL. The structure member is usually 40, but in some special circumstances (like for a test for a specific customer) it needs to be 80. Currently just manually updating each project but wondered if there was something more elegant. I realise a rebuild of both projects is required after any change so maybe I'm wasting my time? Simplest might be to just add a comment in each project to update the other if changed?

Comment: You are a computer programmer. Create some tooling to build your various programs. Pass that tool the necessary information and have it pass those defines on to the various build processes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ....which would lay burden on every future maintainer. If the very language does not provide hooks into compilation process such a solution might taint build process with non-obvious dependencies

Comment: @AlainD can your DLL just export two APIs - `FunctionName40` and `FunctionName80` ? so only EXE would be different ?

Comment: can C++ compile file like `const SZ = 80; int arr[SZ];` ? if it can, then there seems no problem

Comment: @David: while I agree with that as general sentiment, there is a drawback: if you can't define the constant in one place, it is slightly harder to keep them aligned, or you (or the next developer) may forget to do that for one of them.

Comment: @rudy that's why you build a tool to keep things in sync.

Comment: in this specific case having the constant defined in a separate include file that is shared by both C++ and Delphi projects seems quite possible

Comment: @Arioch'The: That's what would be ideal, but unless you can tell the Delphi compiler to ignore the C++ bits (and vice versa), this doesn't appear to be viable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Like the idea of writing a separate tool. A thought popped into my head after reading that comment about having a spreadsheet with a in-built VBA macro. The macro is called as a pre-build step to generate a .inc file (for Delphi) and .h file (for C++) prior to build. Was that the sort of thing you had in mind? Love it...but Arioch does have a point that it lays a burden onto future maintainers. Would have to be well-documented (as with any code, I guess).

Comment: Excel and VBA would be the last thing in my mind ever. Use an a scripting language. Such as Python. A build process is part of any well run project. Write it yourself so that you can control it. Don't tell me you build from the IDE for release.

Comment: Excel and VBA was just a suggestion, I get the idea.

Comment: Alain, I can only repeat the question I asked yesterday:   
can C++ compile file like const SZ = 80; int arr[SZ]; ? if it can, then there seems no problem

Comment: Make a shared text file with content NAME=VALUE and include it into both C++ and Delphi sources, if the prior answer is positive

Comment: As the most ugly option - make a text file containing only the value (40 or 80) and include that file instead of constant into the type declaration itself.  `const MyTypeSize = {$Include value.txt}; type MYType = array[1..{$Include value.txt}] of byte;` - ugly but should work

Answer (score 1):

Here some links which may help:

- If you need to convert *C++ header* files to *Delphi* you may try [JEDI API Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/).
- If you need to convert *Delphi* sources to *C++ header files* you may need to create such utility yourself. I think [DelphiAST](https://github.com/RomanYankovsky/DelphiAST) could be a good start for it.